# PhantomJS to get infos from facebook's ad planner

Tags: facebook, authentication, mechanize, phantomjs

I would like to do a script that automatically gets some numbers from https://www.facebook.com/ads/create/ once a week. For example the number of facebook users of a certain country. Nothing really fancy.

I tried to use PhantomJS and managed to log into facebook (over its mobile website) but if I call https://www.facebook.com/ads/create/ afterwards, facebook always seems to recognize that I don't use a regular browser (of course I tried to use various headers of other browsers.)

I also tried to do it with python/mechanize and other tools like that but always failed.

Does anyone think this is even possible? If yes, how can facebook be tricked? :)

Comment: you could try with rotating agents on mechanize.

Comment: What do you mean? Trying if it works with any of the predefined mechanize agents? I think I have tried most of them already.

Comment: yes, maybe you could shara what you tried so far in mechanize.